# Angular ng-include and specifying controllers

Tags: angularjs, ng-controller, angularjs-ng-include

Suppose I have index.html which has mainCtrl as its controller. If I use an ng-include in index.html to include partial html code that is saved on a separate page, does the included page have the mainCtrl or do I need to specify it again on that page?

Comment: If including it inside element which has mainCtrl then yes it will automatically share parent scope (mainCtrl), otherwise no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**mainCtrl** and it's scope will be also available in your included part.

Comment: Not always true. If the ng-include is not inside an element referencing the controller, then the controller won't be available in the included template.

Comment: @wdanda "Suppose I have index.html which has mainCtrl as its controller. If I use an ng-include in index.html to include partial html code.." 
**in** index.html , that has mainCtrl as it's controller

Answer (score 1):

If including it inside element which has mainCtrl then yes it will automatically share parent scope (mainCtrl), otherwise no.

Answer (score 0):

## ngInclude Directive

### Directive Info

This directive creates new scope.

You can also find a good example in the below link.

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude